# Как правильно импортировать lodash?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, импорт, модули, lodash

Сам я не любитель `lodash`, но пришел на (фронтовый что важно) проект где активно используется эта библиотека.
До сих пор ее использовали так:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

а потом например

```
_.flatten(some)
```

Для лучшего тришейкинга и уменьшения размера бандла начал переписывать импорты так:

```
import { flatten } from "lodash";
```

Но беда в том, что в некоторых местах используют конструкцию `_(some)` для которой приходится импортировать библиотеку через звездочку.

Подскажите, есть ли способ "экономично" импортировать эту функцию из пакета?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464732/1016033

Comment: https://link.medium.com/tnWBmEBH8Y